# make a phone call without the user interactions android

Tags: android

I am using this code to make a phone call without the user interactions 
but I am getting these errors.

1.error: cannot find symbol variable bundle

2. error: cannot find symbol variable Uri
3. error: cannot find symbol variable context

**Here is the code**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bundle.getString("trephone#")));
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: make sure that the imported R is not from another module. I had moved a class from a module to the main project, and the R was the one from the module.

Comment: can your share more code snippets for easy to understand your problem

Comment: how can I make sure that the imported R is not from another module ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do without user intervention, but there is one way
Here it is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dial("000000");
        }
    });
}

private void dial(final String phoneNumber) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber, null)));
}
```

Comment: this one with user interaction ?

Comment: on some phones - without